# Bayesian network probability truth table

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I am working on a bayesian network problem and have been given the following table of data:

```
 A  |  B  |  P(D=true | A,B)
 ---------------------------
 F     F           0.9
 F     T           0.6 
 T     F           0.5 
 T     T           0.1
```

If I wanted to determine the simple probability of D being true, how would I do this? I think that all of these events in the table are mutually exclusive, since A and B can only take on 1 value at a time. Would I just add all these probabilities to get P(D being true)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to weight the P(D) terms by probabilities for the various (A,B) combinations.

Comment: $P(D=1) = P(A=0,B=0)P(D=1|A=0,B=0)+P(A=0,B=1)P(D=1|A=0,B=1)+...$ So if each pairing for $A,B$ were equally likely, you would just average the values of the right.

Comment: @herbsteinberg isnt that already whats happening in the tables? I dont understand what you mean by weight the P(D)?

Comment: @Mark ahh I see what you are doing. I will give that a shot. Thank you very much!